# Retrofit2 обработка разных ответов от сервера

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Начал использовать retrofit2.
До этого по старинке парсил ответ в ручную.

У нас сервер на один запрос может вернуть два разных ответа в зависимости от ситуации на сервере, мобильное приложение должно отреагировать в зависимости от ответа.

Везде примеры как делают запрос на сервер и получают одну структуру данных в виде ответа.

А как обработать совершенно разные структуру от сервера?

Допустим полностью все данные о пользователе или структуру с описанием ошибки, которая ничего общего с структурой пользователя не имеет?

Буду признателен за небольшой пример. Спасибо!

Comment: вы хотите отобразить эту ошибку или обработать ее как-то?

Comment: Допустим я хочу ее обработать. Потому что пример с ошибкой частный.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, тут можно реализовать следующее: создать обертку для двух разных ответов, типа класс, который содержит внутри два возможных типа(класса), с возможностью проверки, какой тип ответа он содержит. Далее для Retrofit создать конвертер и преобразовать два разных ответа в один и вернуть его. Далее уже  в коде уже работать с оберткой, проверяя тип возвращенного ответа.

Я так предполагаю, что тут замешан RPC, когда может вернутся "нормальный" ответ, а при ошибке возвращается структура с информацией об ошибке, при этом код ответа будет 200.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы обработать ошибку при работе с Retrofit2 не обязательно создавать что-то новое или менять структуру ответа. У вас сервер может давать совершенно разные ответы, например:

1. 200 - все хорошо
2. 500 - проблемы на сервере
3. 400, 401, 402, 403 - проблема в том что вы отправляете или запрашиваете.

Вот как можно обработать негативный ответ сервера:

```
ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
try {
if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("refresh_token_expired")) {
} 
if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("access_token_expired")) {
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

дальше вы прописываете необходимые действия при возникновении той или иной ошибки. Удачи :)

Comment: Повторюсь, пример с ошибкой это только пример. А что делать если это не ошибка а просто ответ с другой структурой?

Comment: я думаю что если будет ответ с другой структурой то значит и адрес по которому вы обращаетесь будет другим, сомневаюсь что сервер может слать на один и тот же запрос, ответ с разными структурами.

Comment: У нас сервер так отвечает. Вопрос же не в сомнениях, а в том как решить поставленную задачу. Ретрофит этого не позволяет сделать? Вот в этом я точно сомневаюсь.

Comment: а от чего зависит тип ответа сервера?

Comment: Какая разница? Вы капаете не в ту сторону. Мне нужно решение - даем запрос на урл, от сервера может прийти ответ1 или ответ2. Как в ретрофит понять какой ответ пришел и обработать его?

Comment: можете пример дать, потому что не очень понимаю что у вас там происходит, вообще чисто гипотетически можно отлавливать код ответа и дальше уже тащить из ответа все данные которые вам нужны, но тогда нужно будет в класс-модель вкинуть все возможные поля которые вам будут приходить.

Answer (score 0):

Самое универсальное решение: получайте результат от сервера в виде простой строки, без автоматической конвертации.

Правда придется брутфорсом перебирать все варианты конвертации строки: если преобразовалось в json - хорошо, пробуем преобразовать в gson (`List<Items>`, `Car`, `Dog`, `Document` и т.д.)

Не получилось преобразовать? Ищем ключевую подстроку (можно использовать regex) и определяем по ней, что к нам пришло. Парсим, парсим, парсим...

И т.д.